# Having issues creating and saving an instance of a nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, associations, has-many, belongs-to

I am running into issues creating and saving an instance of a nested resource and I haven't been able to figure how to remedy this. I have a User and a Jobs model (User has_many jobs and Job belongs_to User). Existing users should be able to post/create jobs through there account.

In console @user.jobs.build / @user.jobs.create execute fine. In views, however, when I click "Post a Job" and attempt to submit the corresponding form, I receive the below errors (depending on what I change):

1. When I submit the form to jobs#new with @user = User.find(params[:id]) and @job = @user.jobs.build(user_jobs_params), the error is:

   `ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty:`
2. When I submit the form to jobs#create with @user = User.find(params[:id]) and @job = @user.jobs.build(user_jobs_params), the error is:

   `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find User with 'id'=):`

   `SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", nil], ["LIMIT", 1]]`
3. When I submit the form to jobs#create with @user = current_user and @job = @user.jobs.build(user_jobs_params), the error is:

   `ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty:`

   `SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", nil], ["LIMIT", 1]]`
4. When I submit the form to jobs#create with @user = current_user and @job = @user.jobs.build(user_jobs_params) set my form up with <%= form_with(model: @user, :url => { :controller => "job", :action => "create" }, :html => {:method => :post}) do |f| %>, the error is:

   `ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty:`

   `SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", nil], ["LIMIT", 1]]`

I been wrecking my brains trying to understand why user_id is nil/unable to be found when in the server log, the user is loaded on every page of the website. Especially confused for the cases using current_user as that's defined in my sessions helper and needs to exist for a user to log in). I also tried doing this with @user = User.new and ran into some other errors that I can add if that's the appropriate way to do this, however, that didn't seem to make sense since I'm not trying to create a new user with the jobs posts but rather create a job that belongs_to an existing user.

UPDATING: 
Jobs Controller

```
def new
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @job = @user.jobss.build
  end
```

Tried pushing create two different ways and neither worked!

```
  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @job = @user.jobs.build(user_job_params)
    @job.save
  end

  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @job = @user.jobs.create(user_job_params)
  end

  private

  def user_job_params
    params.require(:job).permit(:job_name, 
                              :job_description, :job_deadline, :organization,
                              :organization_liaison_name, :organization_liaison_email)
  end
end
```

Top of User Controller

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :partner_profile
  has_one :student_profile
  has_many :jobs, inverse_of: :user


  accepts_nested_attributes_for :student_profile, :partner_profile, update_only: true
  attr_accessor :remember_token, :activation_token, :reset_token
  before_save   :downcase_email
  before_create :create_activation_digest, :build_profile
  validates :first_name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  validates :last_name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                      format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                      uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_nil: true
  validates :account_type, presence: true
```

I am running into issues creating and saving an instance of a nested resource and I haven't been able to figure how to remedy this. I have a User and a Jobs model (User has_many jobs and Job belongs_to User). Existing users should be able to post/create jobs through there account.

In console @user.jobs.build / @user.jobs.create execute fine. In views, however, when I click "Post a Job" and attempt to submit the corresponding form, I receive the below errors (depending on what I change):

1. When I submit the form to jobs#new with @user = User.find(params[:id]) and @job = @user.jobs.build(user_jobs_params), the error is:

   `ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty:`
2. When I submit the form to jobs#create with @user = User.find(params[:id]) and @job = @user.jobs.build(user_jobs_params), the error is:

   `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find User with 'id'=):`

   `SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", nil], ["LIMIT", 1]]`
3. When I submit the form to jobs#create with @user = current_user and @job = @user.jobs.build(user_jobs_params), the error is:

   `ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty:`

   `SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", nil], ["LIMIT", 1]]`
4. When I submit the form to jobs#create with @user = current_user and @job = @user.jobs.build(user_jobs_params) set my form up with <%= form_with(model: @user, :url => { :controller => "job", :action => "create" }, :html => {:method => :post}) do |f| %>, the error is:

   `ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty:`

   `SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", nil], ["LIMIT", 1]]`

I been wrecking my brains trying to understand why user_id is nil/unable to be found when in the server log, the user is loaded on every page of the website. Especially confused for the cases using current_user as that's defined in my sessions helper and needs to exist for a user to log in). I also tried doing this with @user = User.new and ran into some other errors that I can add if that's the appropriate way to do this, however, that didn't seem to make sense since I'm not trying to create a new user with the jobs posts but rather create a job that belongs_to an existing user.

UPDATING: 
Jobs Controller

```
def new
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @job = @user.jobss.build
  end

  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @job = @user.jobs.build(user_job_params)
    @job.save
  end

  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @job = @user.jobs.create(user_job_params)
  end

  private

  def user_job_params
    params.require(:job).permit(:job_name, 
                              :job_description, :job_deadline, :organization,
                              :organization_liaison_name, :organization_liaison_email)
  end
end
```

Top of User Controller

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :partner_profile
  has_one :student_profile
  has_many :jobs, inverse_of: :user


  accepts_nested_attributes_for :student_profile, :partner_profile, update_only: true
  attr_accessor :remember_token, :activation_token, :reset_token
  before_save   :downcase_email
  before_create :create_activation_digest, :build_profile
  validates :first_name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  validates :last_name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                      format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                      uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_nil: true
  validates :account_type, presence: true
```

Job Creation ERROR

```
Started POST "/users/2/jobs" for XXXX at 2018-07-05 19:42:33 +0000
Cannot render console from XXXX! Allowed networks: XXXX
Processing by JobsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"I1/okrk5p125FKrFx2Nhu4L78UNJFQIZPgjWfnzVnCCh5vzr9AuNxFkl2jHD+qjshlh170OI1o0Av8yGlek4Aw==", "job"=>{"job_name"=>"ega", "job_description"=>"", job_deadline(2i)"=>"", "job_deadline(3i)"=>"", "job_deadline(1i)"=>"", "organization"=>"", "organization_liaison_name"=>"", "organization_liaison_email"=>"", "program_manager_first_name"=>"", "program_manager_last_name"=>"", "program_manager_email"=>"", "program_manager_phone_number"=>""}, "commit"=>"Submit A New Job!", "user_id"=>"2"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (2.9ms)  INSERT INTO "jobs" ("user_id", job_name", "status", "job_description", "organization", "organization_liaison_name", "organization_liaison_email", "program_manager_first_name", "program_manager_last_name", "program_manager_email", "program_manager_phone_number", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["user_id", 2], ["job_name", "ega"], ["status", "Pending Approval"], ["job_description", ""], ["organization", ""], ["organization_liaison_name", ""], ["organization_liaison_email", ""], ["program_manager_first_name", ""], ["program_manager_last_name", ""], ["program_manager_email", ""], ["program_manager_phone_number", ""], ["created_at", "2018-07-05 19:42:33.406656"], ["updated_at", "2018-07-05 19:42:33.406656"]]
   (5010.0ms)  commit transaction
   (2.3ms)  rollback transaction
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5023ms (ActiveRecord: 5015.4ms)



ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (SQLite3::BusyException: database is locked: commit transaction):

app/controllers/jobs_controller.rb:28:in `create'
```

Comment: _"When I submit the form to jobs#new"_ - That's not what `new` is for. It is for initializing a resource and rendering the form.

Comment: _"ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find User with 'id'=)"_ - Most probably, your `params[:id]` is `nil`. Can you show the result of `rake routes`? Add to question.

Comment: _"ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty:"_ - What does `user_job_params` contain?

Comment: Please post the controller code for `create` action along with all the before filters and methods used inside it.

Comment: where is the New Job Form ? inside it's own view (meaning views>jobs>new.html.erb with route `new_user_job_path`) ? or inside the user show view ?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh - Yes, I know that's not what jobs#new, I just tried something nonsensical in my stream of tweaks - I'm new to rails so I thought I would try anything

Comment: @sovalina, the view is in views > jobs > new.html.erb and is using user_jobs_path in form_for as this is a nested resource. With the below suggestion from Matt, form seems to be going through alright but in create, job won't post. I'll update with create action to see if you guys can see why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are in the JobsController and not the UsersController, you need to grab the user's id with user_id from the params (not id). Try using...

```
@user = User.find(params[:user_id])
```

Also, you should not be passing in the params in the new action...only pass them in during the create action.

In the new action

```
@job = @user.jobs.build
```

In the create action

```
@job = @user.jobs.build(user_jobs_params)
```

Comment: :user_id worked! However, now I'm having an issue saving the record to db - there's a rollback and it says create is the issue, create action looks like this: def create
    [at]user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    [at]job = [at]user.jobs.build(user_job_params)
    [at]job.save
  end
    and def user_job_params
    params.require(:job).permit(:job_name, 
                                  :job_description, etc...........)

error is on the create; I also tried [at]user.jobs.create(user_job_params) and that also had a rollback failure. No before filters/actions on jobs.

Comment: Failure also reads: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (SQLite3::BusyException: database is locked: commit transaction but I don't have a console open or anything

Comment: try running `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("BEGIN TRANSACTION; END;")` in the rails console

Comment: If that doesn't work, please post your log output to your original question (not in the comments) where the error occurred, starting with `Started POST`

Comment: Did that and still getting the same response commit transaction
   (2.3ms)  rollback transaction
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5023ms (ActiveRecord: 5015.4ms)
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (SQLite3::BusyException: database is locked: commit transaction):
  
app/controllers/jobs_controller.rb:28:in `create'

Comment: Ok updating the original question

Comment: Wait...do you have two create actions in the JobsController? Or is that a copy/paste error?

Comment: No copy/paste error! Was just showing that I tried to push the save through [at]job.save and also [at]user.jobs.create to see if that made a difference - will update to explain!

Comment: have you tried...`bundle exec rails db:reset`? If that doesn't work then the issue is that something else is using the database at the same time that you are trying to create the job. My first step would be to comment out the callbacks before_save and before_create and see if it works. If your still stuck, post another qeustion about that specific error...good luck!

Comment: bundle exec rails db:reset was the solution! Everything went through perfectly!